# Changing shared memory size in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, shared-memory, docker-swarm

I'm currently having some issues with the shared memory in one of my containers.

I have a docker-compose file in where I expect to be able to set the size. I basically converted an old docker run that had a `--shm-size 16gb`. I would guess it's as easy as adding `shm_size:16gb` to my service in the compose file.

Adding it just gives me the info: `Ignoring unsupported options: shm_size`.

I did check the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#domainname-hostname-ipc-mac_address-privileged-read_only-shm_size-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir), but it didn't really help me.

**Just to clarify, it's not in the build but really for the "running" state.**

Does one of you ever had this issue/know how to solve it?

Setup:

- docker swarm with 7 nodes
- Service should run on just a single node
- Only running stacks
- 64 GB RAM host
- 32 GB shm (host)
- Docker version 18.09.7, build 2d0083d
- Using v 3.7 in my compose file

Compose file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  server:
    shm_size: 16GB # <<<<<<< This fails
    image: local_repo/my_app:v1-dev
    command: run
    environment:
      - UPDATES=enabled
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: data
        target: /var/lib/my_app/
      - type: volume
        source: db
        target: /var/lib/postgresql/10/main
    networks:
      - xxx_traefik
    deploy:
     mode: replicated
     labels:
        - traefik.docker.network=xxx_traefik
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.port=80
        - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:my_container.xxx.com
        - traefik.backend.loadbalancer.stickiness=true
        - traefik.protocol=http
     replicas: 1
     placement:
       constraints:
         - node.hostname==node2

volumes:
  db:
   external: true
  data:
   external: true
networks:
  xxx_traefik:
    external: true
# shm_size: 16GB  <<<<<<< Also tried to put it here since documentation doesn't show indents
```

Any help is appreciated:)

Answer (score 22):

It should be below service, I can verify it, but here is what offical documentation said

`SHM_SIZE`

> Added in version 3.5 file format
>
> Set the size of the /dev/shm partition for this build’s containers.
>   Specify as an integer value representing the number of bytes or as a
>   string expressing a byte value.

```
build:
  context: .
  shm_size: '2gb'
```

[compose-file-SHM_SIZE](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/)

Here is test

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  your_service:
    image: alpine
    command: ash -c "sleep 2 && df /dev/shm"
    shm_size: 2gb
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I see that that works.

I see that I never mentioned it, but I'm using a docker stack deploy to deploy it.

In there it says it's ignored.

I can't find anything in the docs that mentions that it's ignored like with the other options.

Am I wrong or should it also just work in a docker stack deploy?

Comment: oh then it is issue with docker swarm, according to this issue https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/26714 swarm does not support. but you can check for workaround. to pass it build time

Comment: I see, thanks!
The workaround only seems to be for the build, not for the run...

Comment: Haha no I needed it for the run part.
Found a workaround solution:
```
volumes:
    - type: tmpfs
      target: /dev/shm
      tmpfs:
        size: 16000000000 #~ 16gb
```