# Docker shared memory size out of bounds or unhandled system error, NCCL version 2.7.8

Tags: docker, docker-compose, portainer

The following error(s) and solution go for deploying a stack through YAML in [portainer](https://www.portainer.io/) but they can surely be applied to docker otherwise.

Environment:

```
PYTORCH="1.8.0"
CUDA="11.1"
CUDNN="8"
GPUs: Geforce RTX 3090
```

When trying to [train a model](https://mmaction2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#train-a-model) with a single GPU, a shared memory size out of bounds error is thrown.

Also, when I used more GPUs (4), I got a different error, namely

```
RuntimeError: NCCL error in: /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1614378083779/work/torch/lib/c10d/ProcessGroupNCCL.cpp:825, unhandled system error, NCCL version 2.7.8
```

However, if you [enable debugging](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/nccl/user-guide/docs/env.html) of NCCL, you will notice that at its root, it's actually a shared memory size error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that by default, the size of the shared memory is limited to [64mb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30210362/how-to-increase-the-size-of-the-dev-shm-in-docker-container). The solution to this error therefore, as shown in [this](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/2244) issue is to increase the size of shared memory.

Hence, the first idea that comes to mind would be simply defining something like `shm_size: 9gb` in the YAML file of the stack. However, this might not work as shown for e.g in [this](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/26714) issue.

Therefore, in the end, I had to use the following workaround (also described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58952478/changing-shared-memory-size-in-docker-compose), but poorly documented):

```
volumes:
      - data-transfer:/mnt/data_transfer
      - type: tmpfs
        target: /dev/shm
        tmpfs:
          size: 9000000000
```

For this to work, however, you should make sure that the version of the stack YAML file is in its latest (otherwise you might get a syntax error), e.g. 3.7. A complete stack YAML file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  mmaction2:
    shm_size: 256m # doesn't work
    image: something 
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - data-transfer:/mnt/data_transfer
      - type: tmpfs
        target: /dev/shm
        tmpfs:
          size: 9000000000 # ~9gb

volumes:
  # local
  data-transfer:
    driver: local
    name: data-transfer
```